# Body.setGravityScale in andengine GLES2?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want to make an object that is not affected by gravity. 
I tried applying a force in the opposite direction (-1 * body.getMass () * gravity) does not work.

To the object I apply a impulse for it to move horizontally from left to right but I want to stay on a high. I have seen Body.setGravityScale exists but is not implemented in the box2d extension for GLES2 andengine.

Does anyone know how I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just "shooting from the hip" but what about a prismatic joint?  Could you connect the object to an non-invisible horizontal line body so that it will only move left or right?

Answer (score 1):

I think Kinematic Body is the body you are looking for. In Andngine there are 3 types of bodies:

- Dynamic Body: These are real world bodies.They are affected by gravity, collisions etc.
- Static Body: These bodies are not affected by any kind of external force.Even if you give them velocity, they won't move.
- Kinematic Body: This is the body type that you are looking for. Kinematic bodies are not affected by gravity but if you apply them force manuelly (e.g. `setVelocity(5,0)` ) they move. They are a mixture of Static and Dynamic Body

Lastly, you can have a Kinematic body with:

> yourBody =
>   PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(yourPhysicsWorld,yourSprite,BodyType.KinematicBody,yourFixtureDefinition);